# Fetch timestamp of the midnight before a given timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

Given any unix-timestamp T, I want to fetch the timestamp of the midnight before T.

The given timestamp can be any integer: now, today, (not too far[*]) in the future or (not too far[*]) in the past.

Is there a cleaner way then (pseudocode):

```
<?php
$midnight = strtotime("{date('d',$ts)}-{date('m',$ts)}-{date('Y', $ts)} midnight");
?>
```

Thanks.

[*] somewhere between 1990 and 2020.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it as

```
$midnight = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',$ts).' 00:00:00');
```

...but whether that is cleaner/better is debatable...

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that the route via strtotime was the only "pragmatic" approach. Yours is the most clean of these.

Answer (score 3):

Since a full day is 86400 seconds, you should be able to do this:

```
$midnight = $ts - $ts%86400;
```

However, this wouldn't consider any leap seconds that might have been applied to the unix timestamp.

This would be a lot more performant than using strtotime but would probably only matter if you would do this in big tight loops.

Answer (score 1):

Et voila'

```
<?php    
$midnight = strtotime(date('d-m-Y',$ts));
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$ts);       // output 03-11-2011 12:43:41
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$midnight); // ouput 03-11-2011 00:00:00
?>
```